# upload plugin in shopware store(The essential composer.json file for the plugin was not in the expected folder)

Tags: shopware

I want to upload a plugin in the Shopware store
after upload and defined require filed when i try to submitting my plugin for code review i got an error

```
Basic plugin analysis failed.
The required composer.json file was not found
Context: [
 • reason: The essential composer.json file for the plugin was not in the expected folder
]
Documentation: https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/references-internals/plugins/plugin-base-class?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/references-internals/plugins
```

I googling about this error and find this issue https://forum.shopware.com/discussion/69413/json-composer-file-nicht-gefunden-beim-upload-in-den-community-store

My technical name in  the Shopware panel is:

```
xxx46AKGoogleMapPlugin
```

And my composer.json is

```
.
"name": "aks/google-map-plugin",
.
.
"license": "proprietary",
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Aks\\GoogleMapPlugin\\": "src/"
      }
  },
  "require": {
        "shopware/core": "6.*",
        "shopware/storefront": "6.*",
        "shopware/administration": "6.*"
  },
  "extra": {
        "shopware-plugin-class": "Aks\\GoogleMapPlugin\\AKGoogleMapPlugin",
.
.
.
```

And it is my base class plugin. I used **Aks\GoogleMapPlugin** namespace  wherever I needed

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Aks\GoogleMapPlugin;
.
.
.
class AKGoogleMapPlugin extends Plugin
{
.
```

.
.

What is my wrong ? My folder name is **AKGoogleMapPlugin** and i create zip file in Ubuntu (AKGoogleMapPlugin->composer.json , AKGoogleMapPlugin->src->AKGoogleMapPlugin.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your technical name is `xxx46AKGoogleMapPlugin` then your shopware plugin class and the folder should be named exactly like that.

You should also consider using your vendor prefix `xxx46AK` as a part of your composer namespace, that way your namespace is unique.

Please refer to these guidelines: https://docs.shopware.com/en/plugin-standard-for-community-store#the-required-composer-json-file-was-not-found

Comment: Hi .thank you .I defined  AKGoogleMapPlugin for technical name  in Shopware panel and prefix xxx46 defined  automatically by Shopware.I have to use of prefix xxx46  in my plugin too?I wondered so if user run bin/console plugin:list he/she  see  xxx46AKGoogleMapPlugin in list plugin